# Error when Starting CYGWin SSH daemon on windows 7 home edition

Tags: hadoop, cygwin

I am using Windows 7 Home edition, trying to install `CYGWin SSH daemon`.
Successfully done the same, but when I run the same, I see error in `C:\cygwin\var\log\sshd.log` file

```
Privilege separation user sshd does not exist
```

I understand that I need to create (or enable) the above user, not sure how? I found the link that says it's not possible according to this [website](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/7539-local-users-groups-manager-open.html).

More details & screen shots at this [link](http://lavnish.blogspot.in/2012/12/hadoop-on-windows-7-with-eclipse.html)

Let me know if I need to provide some more input.

Answer (score 1):

You can either create the sshd user or disable privilege separation in sshd.config
See [here](http://www.webicy.com/web-server-administration/49215-starting-sshd-privilege-separation-user-does-not-exist.html#.UXOta7XdfN1) for the details